# How to include last, filtered, sorted child row in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, domain-driven-design

I want to include a single child row, filtered, and only include the last one found.

I can do this manually & inefficiently as follows:

```
var persons = dbContext.Persons.ToList();

foreach (var person in persons)
{
    var lastMatchingNote = person.Notes
              .Where(x => x.Type == 5)
              .OrderBy(x => x.Date)
              .LastOrDefault();
}
```

But this re-queries for each person.

Alternatively, I could Include() the notes in the original query then filter in memory:

```
var persons = dbContext.Persons.Include("Notes").ToList();
```

But this will load all notes which is inefficient.

What's the best way to do this in EF6?

(Stored procedures, views or other exotic solutions are options, but I would prefer a pure LINQ-to-Entities solution. Creating a computed field would work too, if I can prevent it from being loaded on all other queries involving Person.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided to create a separate view for this extra value. This might seem like overkill, but the performance is excellent and it can retrieve all the values in a single query, which is the priority in my scenario given the performance requirements with large datasets.

So I have the following view:

```
CREATE VIEW vwperson_lastproactivenote as 
SELECT people.person_id AS id, 
    (SELECT max(notes.note_date) AS max
     FROM notes
     WHERE notes.person_id = people.person_id AND notes.note_type_id = 5) AS date
FROM people;
```

Then I can build a model which shares the primary key with Person:

```
public class PersonLastProactiveCall
{
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}

...

// On person model
[ForeignKey("Id")]
public virtual PersonLastProactiveCall LastProactiveCall { get; set; }
```

So eventually I can call it as follows:

```
DataContext.Set<Person>().Include("LastProactiveCall").Where(...);

person.LastProactiveCall.Date  // <-- Yay!!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

Try querying the database like this:

```
var results = 
    (from p in dbContext.Persons
     select new {
         person = p,
         lastMatchingNote = p.Notes.Where(x => x.Type == 5)
                                   .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                                   .First()
     })
    .ToList();
```

Or like this:

```
var results = 
    (from p in dbContext.Persons
     let lastMatchingNote = p.Notes.Where(x => x.Type == 5)
                                   .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                                   .First()
     select new { person = p, lastMatchingNote })
    .ToList();
```

With this approach you can tweak the columns in the result set, giving you much finer control over the actual query.

Comment: I like the syntax, but is LINQ-to-Entities smart enough to put the sub-query into SQL? I'm guessing it will actually re-run the sub query  for each Person found.

Comment: @BrendanHill As I have it written here, I wouldn't guarantee that it will only run a single query; you should probably try it yourself just to make sure. But if you change the result set to just include the properties you're interested in (just simple properties, not navigation properties), then it will.

Comment: Cool. Unfortunately this won't work for my project as it uses PostgreSQL (didn't realize it would be relevant to mention) and when I try this it errors out with "OUTER APPLY not supported". Also guaranteeing a single query is essential.

Comment: @BrendanHill Part of the point of EF is that, ideally, you don't have to worry *that* much about how the Linq query translates into a SQL query. If executing a single query is a hard requirement, I'd definitely go with a stored proc.  Unfortunately I've never used EF with PostgreSQL so I'm not familiar with its limitations.